# Что нужно учесть при создании чата

Tags: безопасность, проектирование

В качестве отдельной части приложения реализую многопользовательский чат в реальном времени.

Базовые вещи, по типу отключения и блокировки клиентов, отправляющих спам, реализованы.

XSS-атаки на текстовое поле ввода исключены использованием составленных хорошими людьми regexp.

Может быть кто знает, какие еще ловушки могут быть зарыты в данной теме?

Comment: `XSS-атаки...исключены использованием...regexp` - очень странно звучит. При выводе пользователю спецсимволы меняете на сущности и все, ни каких регулярок не нужно.

Comment: XSS атаки предотвращаются htmlspecialchars()

Comment: SQL инъекции если есть GET запросы

Comment: @Visman подразумевал здесь использование готового решения. В частности express-sanitizer для экосистемы node хорошо справляется с задачей. Правда он целиком вырезает участки, которые могут запустить исполняемую среду. Сначала не понял про html-сущности, а это как раз и есть та самая замена символов например,  & в &amp; < в &lt;  > в &gt; " в &quot;  ' в &#x27, / в &#x2F. Это собственно 6 основных символов, которые нужно либо переводить в сущности, либо удалять из контекста.

Comment: @Duoxx спасибо за просвящение по способу такой же реализации в PHP-проектах

Answer (score -1):

Есть ли у тебя защита от [тайминговой атаки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)? Если нет, то [вот тут решение](https://habrahabr.ru/company/alfa/blog/338170/). Это важная тема, так как используя тайминговую атаку очень легко подобрать пароль к чужому аккаунту.
Я подозреваю, что твой чат работает на сайте, но если нет, то ещё не забудь про защиту от [MiTM атаки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0). Чтобы защититься достаточно просто не использовать Доверенный Центр Корневых Сертификатов твой операционной системы, а встраивать доверенные сертификаты в код.

Comment: Почему ответ был заминусован? Это связано с тем, что timing attacks не являются как таковой угрозой на практике? Если учесть уровень абстракции js и node - окружения (тот же самый event loop) и прочие затраты времени на уровнях OSI выше 3-го, то этот тип атаки будет работать только на бумаге?

Comment: @MaxBender, спасибо, что понял величину уязвимости.